# Edittext background stretches to fill the entire area

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an edittext for which I want to set below background[image]

but when I set this as background it stretches itself to fit in whole EditText like below image.[image]

and below is my code for xml file for editext

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/add_your_comment"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_search_field"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/post_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tick_selection" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I set the background correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Ok So issue resolved simply by using nine patch image i have got from actionBarsherlock library which is using it for it's search view.

Answer (score 0):

This line.-

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

makes your `TextView` fill the empty width in the `LinearLayout`. Just try and remove it. You should also replace

```
android:padding="5dp"
```

for

```
android:layout_margin="5dp"
```

Comment: Mmh that padding may be messing with the background ass well. Actually, seeing the bottom border it seems the image is stretching more vertically than horizontally. Try setting a margin instead of a padding.

Comment: i tried that also but i no luck.I guess thats because we are setting the backgroud of the  edittext which is trying to strech iteself to fit aroud the editetext.But what i can do to resolve this.

Comment: First off, I'd try copying the same `TextView` as a child of the root view, just to make sure where's the problem: in the `TextView` itself or in its parent. Besides, you can also try setting the `LinearLayout` width to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

Comment: did the same but no benefit.You also try meanwhile i m also trying something.

Comment: it could be possible that the image you are using is larger than the size of the edittext, meaning, the edittext could say occupy upto 100dp space, but the image is meant to occupy 150dp, and so it takes up the whole space ???

Comment: @DharaShah Dont think  that could be the issue.my drawable is of 470X12 pixels do u think it is creating a problem?

Comment: @anshul i guess so. because, there was a time when i used a background that was having a greater height than the textview, and i could see extra space under the textview

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:visibility="visible" >

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/comment"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="add_your_comment"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_search_field"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/post_comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
                android:src="@drawable/tick_selection" />
    </LinearLayout>

   // also use my uploaded image which is editext background i'm apply 9-patch so now it not stretched if editext width is large.
```

[image]